# Finding the order of the inverse image of the multiplicative group of units. Is it possible without brute-force?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

Let's suppose you know the prime factorization of $n$ and you want to compute the order of the surjective inverse image of a mutliplicative group of units modulo $m$.  That is we wish to compute $|\pi^{-1}(\Bbb{Z}_m^{\times})|$ where $\pi:\Bbb{Z}_n\twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{Z}_m$ is the natural surjective ring homomorphism, and where $m = \text{rad}(n)$.

Is there a way to do it?  Does it help if I know the factorization of $n$, so say if $n = p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2}$, then $\Bbb{Z}_n \simeq \Bbb{Z}_{p_1^{k_1}} \times \Bbb{Z}_{p_2^{k_2}}$ by CRT.

Because then isn't the inverse image under $\pi$ of $$\Bbb{Z}_m^{\times} \simeq (\Bbb{Z}_{{p_1}^{k_1}})^{\times} \times (\Bbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{k_2}})^{\times},$$ which would be the intersection:

$$
(\text{pr}_1 \circ \pi)^{-1}(\Bbb{Z}_{p_1^{k_1}}^{\times}) \cap (\text{pr}_2 \circ \pi)^{-1}(\Bbb{Z}_{{p_2}^{k_2}}^{\times})
$$

Is there a formula for the order or is it still an open problem?

Does it help if $\text{rad}(m) = m$ so that $m$ is a product of distinct primes?

Comment: What is $m$? Why did $n$ change to $m$? For there to be a surjection from the integers modulo $n$ to the integers modulo $m$, you need $m$ to divide $n$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, $m$ will divide $n$ always, when I choose $n, m$ in my problem.  In particular, $n = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_r^{k_r}$ and $m$ will always equal $\text{rad}(n)$.

Comment: But you're not saying that; you should really state your initial assumptions explicitly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin fixed in post.

Comment: We know the size of each fiber: if $n=md$, and $a$ satisfies $0\leq a\lt m$, then $\pi^{-1}(a)$ contains the remainders $a$, $a+m$, $a+2m,\ldots, a+(d-1)m$; that is, each fiber has $d$ elements. Since we know the size $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}_m$, doesn't that answer the question? The size is exactly $\frac{n}{m}\varphi(m)$. Every element of $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ is in the inverse image, but the inverse image may contain elements that are not units (e.g., for $m=2$, $n=6$, with $d=3$, the inverse image of the single element is $\{1,3,5\}$, of which $3$ is not a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arturo Magidin has pointed out, $\pi$ is a homomorphism of the additive groups $\Bbb Z_n\to\Bbb Z_m$, therefore $\lvert\pi^{-1}(S)\rvert=\lvert S\cap\operatorname{im}\pi\rvert\times\lvert\ker \pi\rvert$ for all $S\subseteq \Bbb Z_m$. Moreover, $\lvert \Bbb Z^\times_{\operatorname{rad}(n)}\rvert=\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(n))$. Therefore the number you are looking for is $\frac{n}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}\varphi(\operatorname{rad}(n))=\varphi(n)$.

Comment: So you're saying the inverse image is the whole group of units modulo $n$?

Comment: @OlympicComputerChairSitter: In the case where $m$ is the radical, it is *exactly* the whole group of units; in the general case, the inverse image contains the group of units, but may be larger, because some things may be coprime to $m$ but not to $n$. But if every prime that divides $n$ also divides $m$, that doesn't happen, so $\pi(a)$ is a unit if and only if $a$ is a unit.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for your careful attention to this question!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, sorry, you're right. I was confusing it with the group being cyclic. :)